# SQL-like graphical software for entering, creating and displaying many to many tables

Tags: sql

I am looking for something like a GUI on top of SQL.

My use case is trying to record and manage a list of servers, workflows that run on those servers, software licenses that are associated to those servers, and other combinations of data (which may or may not involve those servers).

I currently have a server list in Confluence, but the data is very static and needs to be entered in redundantly which is error prone and a pain to update (which means it doesn't get done).

As a specific example, I have a list of servers which includes IP address, hostname, production status, etc. Additionally, I have a table of workflows, and each workflow relies on one or more servers, and a table of software products, a key, and the server it is installed on.

I am looking for some kind of tool where I would have a way to enter in a new workflow with the list its server dependencies, and enter in a new software product and its server, and then be able to do a query on a server for the workflows that depend on it and the software installed. (This is just an example, what I'm looking for is a more general solution for all kinds of many to many interactions of data).

I could of course do this with raw SQL statements, but it's work and not a general skill, which means again that records won't get updated. I want a way to easily add items to tables, and have new tables be automatically generated from other tables, ideally on a web page with a table that I could link to (Excel is not a solution as exchanging spreadsheets and keeping them up to date is not feasible).

It seems like there must be a product that puts a friendly UI over the power of SQL and is web based. Does anyone have any experience trying to solve this problem?

Comment: How about dBeaver?

Comment: On Windows? Do you have a budget?

Comment: Would prefer something hosted on a server and web accessible. Yes, there is a budget but would have to make a hard sell, so if there was something free or low cost that would appeal.

Comment: For which DBMS?

Comment: I would expect the feature set to be pretty basic SQL, so I wouldn't be too concerned with the underlying DB technology.